# How to extend A object to AB object, without affecting A object when I insert another value to AB object?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Here is my simplified case:

```js
var a = {
 filters: ["aa"]
}
var b = {
 filters:["bb","bbb"]
}
var ab = {
}

$.extend(ab, a);
console.log(JSON.stringify(a)); //{"filters":["aa"]}
console.log(JSON.stringify(ab)); //{"filters":["aa"]}

for (var i = 0; i < b.filters.length; i++){
 ab.filters.push(b.filters[i]); //it only inserts to 'ab', but why 'a' also has it?
}

console.log(JSON.stringify(a)); //{"filters":["aa","bb","bbb"]} -> it should be only "aa", shouldn't it??
console.log(JSON.stringify(ab)); //{"filters":["aa","bb","bbb"]}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

As you can see, I extend the `a` object to `ab` object. Afterward, I insert the `b` object's value to `ab` object. Somehow, the `a` object also has the `b` object's value.

Is there any solution to prevent `b` object to also insert its value to `a` object?

Comment: You need to make a *deep copy*, which `$.extend()` does not do.

Comment: @Pointy it does: http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.extend/#jQuery-extend-deep-target-object1-objectN

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan oh that's right. Well how nice for the OP :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to do a deep copy of the original object by passing `true` as the first parameter of `$.extend`:

```js
var a = { filters: ["aa"] }
var b = { filters: ["bb", "bbb"] }
var ab = {}

$.extend(true, ab, a); // < note true here
console.log(JSON.stringify(a)); // {"filters":["aa"]}
console.log(JSON.stringify(ab)); // {"filters":["aa"]}

for (var i = 0; i < b.filters.length; i++) {
  ab.filters.push(b.filters[i]);
}

console.log(JSON.stringify(a)); // {"filters":["aa"]}
console.log(JSON.stringify(ab)); // {"filters":["aa","bb","bbb"]}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Pass `true` as the first parameter of the extend function to deep copy the object.

`$.extend(true, ab, a);`

https://api.jquery.com/jquery.extend/

Answer (score 0):

Just do:

```
$.extend(ab, JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(a)));
```

Check this [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/ymeendw3/)